# Excess locks on Azure SQL database running create procedure code found in Entity Framework migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am having an issue in my production Azure SQL database. During periods of heavy use, we see a large number of database locks pop up. However, the text command for the locks are for `CREATE PROCEDURE` scripts, which only appear in an EF migration. There are 48 locks of various types for this command, of which a snippet is attached.

Why would there be transactions for a migration that would have already been completed? Or is there another reason why a stored procedure would want to create itself over again? Or is this just a red herring?

[Locking logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iiR8.png)

Comment: It is a look in the running proc

Comment: That's just the text definition for the procedure which is taking the locks. You need to take a look at `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset`, see also https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1811/find-current-running-sql-statement-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks all! I appreciate the clarification!